# My code for a math game is not updating variables in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would appreciate if I could get some help with this code in Python 3:

```
#Import everything and start the variables
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random as random
Positive = ["Yes", "yes", "y", "Y"]
StartupGame=()
EndupGame=()
num1 = "wrong"
num2 = "1"
points = 0

#Whole game def
def game(StartupGame):
    print("Cool, let's start:")
    print("Please enter your name: ")
    name = input()
    print(" ")
    print ("Nice to meet you " + name)
    print ("This game is about math questions. You will get a random question and then will need to proceed to the next one for a total of 5 times. Are you ready?")
    Begin = input ()
    print(" ")
    if Begin in Positive:

#define the difficulty system
        def difficultysystem(dif):
            print("Please select your difficulty: hard, medium, or easy.")
            print("*Note* Please keep in mind you should not use any caps")
            Difficulty = input()
            if Difficulty == "easy":
                num1=(random.randint(1,10))
                num2=(random.randint(1,10))
            elif Difficulty == "medium":
                num1=(random.randint(10,50))
                num2=(random.randint(10,50))
            elif Difficulty == "hard":
                num1=(random.randint(50,100))
                num2=(random.randint(50,100))
            else:
                print("Hey " + name + " seems like we could not find your difficulty, please make sure you wrote it down correctly")
                num1="wrong"
                print(" ")
                difficultysystem(1)

#Call system                
        difficultysystem(1)

#Begin game
        print("Nice, timne to start:")
        print("How much is " + num1 + " * " + num2  + "?")
        Answer1 = input()
        print(" ")
        if num1 * num2 == Answer1:
            print ("Good job!")
            points + 1
        else:
            print("Not quite, the correct answer was" + num1 * num2)


    else:
        print ("Oki doke, bye")
    
#First start input
Start = input("Are you ready to play? ")
if Start in Positive:
    game(1)
```

Everytime I run it, the problem happens in the Begin game portion. Instead of showing the updated values for num1 and num2 that were defined by the difficulty, it is giving the ones at the start of the code. Any ideas of what could be happening?
I already tried running it without the starting variables but then the whole thing goes down because the first def is needs them to run. Also tried changing the values at the beggining of the code but it just ends up giving me the ones I changed.

Comment: The `num1`/`num2` that you are setting inside `difficultysystem` are *local variables*, entirely unrelated to the global variables that you are actually using to play the game.  Those never get changed from their original value.

Comment: it looks like the indentation is incorrect. please amend the syntax errors in the code so
that other users can reproduce the problem quickly:
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's not usually correct to define a function inside `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I wrote a program that creates the game you were trying to make. I didn't use any functions but it has the same functionality as what you were trying to write. I used a while loop instead.

```
import random

times_asked = 0
num1 = 0
num2 = 0
name = input("Please enter your name: \n")
positive = ["yes","y"]
print("Nice to meet you " + name)
print ("This game is about math questions. You will get a random question and then will need to proceed to the next one for a total of 5 times. Are you ready?")
Begin = input()
if Begin.lower() in positive:
  while times_asked < 5:
    Difficulty = input("Please select your difficulty for this round (easy medium, or hard: \n")
    if Difficulty.lower() == "easy":
      num1 = random.randint(1,10)
      num2 = random.randint(1,10)
    elif Difficulty.lower() == "medium":
      num1 = random.randint(10,50)
      num2 = random.randint(10,50)
    else:
      num1 = random.randint(50,100)
      num2 = random.randint(50,100)
    Answer = input(f"What is {num1} * {num2}: \n")
    if int(Answer) == num1 * num2:
      print("Correct, good job!")
    else:
      print(f"Wrong the correct answer was {num1*num2}")
    times_asked += 1
print("Oki doke, bye")
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to have `num1` and `num2` as global variables, so you have to scope them correctly: the keyword `global` is used for that. If you don't use `global` they are *local variables*, as pointed out in the question comments, so the `num1` and `num2` inside the function are *different* from the `num1` and `num2` outside.

Take a look at this example:

```
num1 = 0
num2 = 0

def my_function():
    global num1, num2
    num1 = 24
    num2 = 55
    print(num1, num2)


my_function()
#without the global before, this would print 0 0
print(num1, num2)
```